# Spacemacs and elpa-mirror

Tags: spacemacs, proxy

OS: Windows 10

Spacemacs branch: develop

Hi, I am behind a corporate proxy. I want to use a local version of elpa through d12frosted's *elpa-mirror* (https://github.com/d12frosted/elpa-mirror).
I have tried to put the following at the beginning of dotspacemacs/init function:

```
(setq configuration-layer-elpa-archives
    `(("melpa" . "~/.emacs.d/.elpa-mirror/melpa/")
       ("org" . "~/.emacs.d/.elpa-mirror/org/")
       ("gnu" . "~/.emacs.d/.elpa-mirror/gnu/"))
```

I get an error linked to an attempt to access melpa.org and
indeed:

```
ctrl-h v configuration-layer-elpa-archives
```

shows: ("melpa" "melpa.org/melpa")

I have tried also to put the code in user-init, to no avail.

I also modified the code in:
.emacs.d\core\core-configuration-layer.el
to check if I could override the value at all, again without success.

Comment: The code that you pasted here misses one closing parenthesis. According to the [0.300 release notes](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/develop/core/info/release-notes/0.300.txt), placing the code in your user-init section should be fine; at least it seems to be working here...

Comment: Thanks for your remarks dalanicolai and for pointing me to the notes. It seems indeed that, as of 0.300,  it is now a default behaviour to have a local folder and no need for internet connection, which I was unaware of. Let me try.

Comment: Well, the release notes say it will be the default for the master branch. I am not sure if that implies that the repo will also get downloaded when using the develop branch. Of course currently, the develop branch is the default. I don't find that folder locally here, but it could be that the repo gets downloaded as soon as you point to spacelpa...

Comment: Hum. Strange. It does not for me. I have tried something else which I am going to ask in another question.