# Spacemacs 0.300: installing only with zip and tar.gz archives offline?

Tags: spacemacs, microsoft-windows, package-repositories

OS: Windows 10

Emacs: 27.2

Spacemacs: 0.300

For some reasons, I cannot retrieve spacemacs through git (a complex combination of corporate proxy and other issues). But I can download archives. Being on a corporate machine I cannot import a complete working setup either.

Following a previous question on a related subject ([Spacemacs and elpa-mirror](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68539/spacemacs-and-elpa-mirror?noredirect=1#comment109606_68539)), it has been pointed to me that 0.300 can use the stable elpa and work offline. Here is the release note excerpt:

> Spacemacs downloads the whole ELPA stable repository locally so it means that once it is installed you don't need an Internet connection
> anymore to install any packages covered by Spacemacs layers!
>
> Default installation location of the ELPA stable repository is in:
>
> ```
> ~/.emacs.d/.cache/stable-elpa
> ```

I am wondering if it is possible to install spacemacs entirely by downloading archives. I took some steps in that direction. I:

- downloaded the *develop* zip file from
  https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/
- unzipped it
- created a .emacs.d.cache directory
- downloaded the tar.gz file from
  https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacelpa/archive/v0.400.tar.gz
  and uncompress it as:
  .emacs.d.cache\stable-elpa\27.2\spacepa-0.400\
- had to modify the core/configure_layer code to by pass the
  git clone, which allowed to start the configuration.

At this point, *quelpa* presents the same issue and is being cloned. I did not pursue further down that rabbit hole.

The issue could be that it is assumed an initial git is always possible, which is not my case.

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Aren't there something like 100+ third-party packages that Spacemacs downloads when doing the initial install, all of which are not a part of the Spacmacs repository?  Is it your goal to get a list of all 100+ or so packages and download them too?

Comment: @lawlist. Indeed, these are retrieved from archives, mostly under melpa, org and gnu. d12frosted has set up an elpa-mirror to allow these to be downloaded locally. I was not able to make it work in my new settings though. For 0.300, however, the release notes seem to me to imply an offline use is possible once Spacemacs has been installed. So I guess my question is about can I skip the internet connection altogether, provided I install manually the archive in .cache.